# plugin_not_installed, how do I detect which plugin that is?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have inherited an Ionic / Cordova app that builds and deploys via testflight fine. Running it via ionic serve is fine and I have no error messages or prompts.

But installing it on a Mac, I get the message plugin_not_installed although I cannot see any broken functionality.

So how do I track down what is triggering this message?

Comment: Can you share your error message ?

Comment: all I see is a green flash at the top of the iPad with plugin_not_installed on for a few seconds

Comment: you don't have error in the consol ?

Comment: If you haven't already, you can hook the iPad up via USB cable and run Safari's inspector (instructions: https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/02/remote-debugging-ios-safari-on-os-x-windows-and-linux/). Since it happens at startup, you might need to refresh the inspector to have the console kick out the error properly.

Comment: Thanks. I had found it by trial and error before I saw this. Good to know that there is a better way!